# Google Chrome is breaking my iframe

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe

I have an iframe where the web page inside of the iframe runs a JavaScript redirect to a new page.  On most browsers, the iframe is redirected to the new page. On Chrome however this script acts as a "frame breaker" and the entire page gets redirected.  How do I make chrome act like the other browsers?

To Reproduce this effect on your machine:

1. Open this page: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_height_width
2. Then replace the iframe source with this page:

   src="http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/examples/timedelay.php"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome supports the [sandbox](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_iframe_sandbox.asp) attribute which you can use to prevent the loaded page from breaking out of your iframe.

If you add `sandbox="allow-scripts"` to the iframe in your example it works on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the link of the redirect page and put it in. For example, if www.go.ogle.com/1gsth7uh redircted you to armorgames.com, just put in armorgames.com instead of www.go.ogle.com/1gsth7uh.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this instead of whatever you use for the method:

```
<button onclick ="javascript:ShowHide('iframe')" href="javascript:;" >Show/Hide Iframe</button>
<iframe id="iframe" scr="https://secure.translations.com/ProjectA" style="DISPLAY: none" />
<script language="JavaScript">
function ShowHide(divId)
{
if(document.getElementById(divId).style.display == 'none')
{
document.getElementById(divId).style.display='block';
}
else
{
document.getElementById(divId).style.display = 'none';
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like setting display to none does not prevent the frame from redirecting.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but are you sure that this fixes redirection?  I edited my post to show an example or the redirection issue if you want to take a look.